# Performance between direct key access and object destructuring

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the most efficient code from below.

**Code 1**

```
const {
  type,
  size,
} = props;

console.log(type);
```

**Code 2***

```
console.log(props.type);
```

I read in an article there will be performance impact when you read key value pairs deep below in an object. I know accessing one level is not a huge performance impact. But I want to know from above code examples (Code 1 and Code 2) which will be faster and efficient.

Comment: https://jsperf.com/

Comment: Your sample code 2 will be faster, as you are not creating any extra memory to store values.

Comment: Why not just ....run a benchmark yourself? This might be of use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/benchmark

Comment: @Ryxle check your javascript code in https://jsperf.com/

Comment: @zabusa I created a jsperf test. Please check https://jsperf.com/performance-of-object-destructuring/1

Comment: I don't know why this has down voted! appreciated comment from anyone down voted this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case **definitely the second option** **(strictly this case)**.

There are cases where you'll sacrifice a little bit if efficiency for some readability and that's easy to judge for most people.

see the performance difference is very small but it's there.

[image]

URL: https://jsperf.com/destructuring-performance

Comment: So,destructuring comming with costs.

Answer (score 3):

If you see the transpiled code for the destructing part, you can find that a new variable is being set.

For example:

```
const {
  type,
  size,
} = props;
```

gets converted to

```
var type_1 = props.type; // dummy_name
var size_1 = props.size;
```

So, an extra variable is being set and relatively higher memory consumption. However, the difference in performance is very less.

Comment: @Ryxle Please mark it as correct, if you find it correct.

Comment: I want to know the result in ES6 not performance when converted using Babel. We use Babel for cross browser support for new ES features. So thank you for your response but I'm waiting for a better answer.

Comment: The question was not about *transpilation* efficiency but for the performance of the code, *as-is*. *transpilation* process is not a "must".

Answer (score 1):

In Browser and on my local node application. destructing wins!
the difference was bigger in the browser, But if the transpilers are messing with the js code , then there are chances that destructuring might have a negative impact on the "build" time.

```js
const user = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 30,
  email: 'john@example.com',
};

console.time('Direct Key Access');
for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  const name = user.name;
  const age = user.age;
  const email = user.email;
  
  // Perform an operation with the values
  const result = `${name} is ${age} years old and their email is ${email}`;
}
console.timeEnd('Direct Key Access');

console.time('Destructuring');
for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  const { name, age, email } = user;
  
  // Perform an operation with the values
  const result = `${name} is ${age} years old and their email is ${email}`;
}
console.timeEnd('Destructuring');
```