# Creating custom variants with Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create custom variants for the `Button` component in Material UI.

My first step is to create a component-based off of the `Button` component with the styles that I want:

```
// CTA.js

import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: { // CUSTOM__STYLES },
  label: { // CUSTOM__STYLES },
});

const CTA = ({ children }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Button
      classes={{
        root: classes.root, 
        label: classes.label,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Button>
  );
};
```

I then import that component into a new `Button` component that I am creating as follows:

```
// Button.js
import MuiButton from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import CTA from "./CTA";

const Button = ({ variant, ...muiButtonProps }) => {
  if (variant === "cta") {
    return <CTA {...muiButtonProps} />;
  }
  return <MuiButton {...muiButtonProps} />;
};
```

Now, what I want is to be able to import my new `Button` component and have it work just like a regular Material-UI button component, but with the addition of `variant="cta"`. However, it does not quite work.

For example, take a look at the following:

```
// Header.js
import { Button as MuiButton } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Button } from "@/theme/button.js";

...

<MuiButton variant="outlined">Mui Button</MuiButton>  // works
<Button variant="outlined">Button</Button> // does not work
<Button variant="cta">CTA Button</Button>  // works
```

I see that my new custom Button component works when I use `variant="cta"`, but it does not work when I use any of the built-in Material-UI variant options. I cannot figure out what that is. I would have thought that `<Button variant="outlined">` would work just like `<MuiButton variant="outlined">`. But that is not the case.

Any idea why not and how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two options are possible, it dont work cause you destruct "variant" and don't forward it to your MuiButton.

You can do it this way in your Button.js

```
const Button = ({ variant, ...muiButtonProps }) => {
  if (variant === "cta") {
    return <CTA {...muiButtonProps} />;
  }
  return <MuiButton variant={variant} {...muiButtonProps} />;
};
```

or

```
const Button = (muiButtonProps) => {
  if (muiButtonProps.variant === "cta") {
    return <CTA {...muiButtonProps} />;
  }
  return <MuiButton {...muiButtonProps} />;
};
```

Take a look at the docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

```
// Stage 4(finished) proposal
({a, b, ...rest} = {a: 10, b: 20, c: 30, d: 40});
console.log(a); // 10
console.log(b); // 20
console.log(rest); // {c: 30, d: 40}
```

Comment: Great answer -- it's a shame I can only upvote your answer once.  Thanks.

Comment: P.S.  Is there an advantage (besides aesthetics) of one version over the other?

Comment: If you look at it from a performance perspective, direct access is faster and if its transpiled(babel) it use less memory than destructuring, but it is minimal. See also this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47989352/performance-between-direct-key-access-and-object-destructuring/47989440)

Answer (score 49):

In Material-UI v5, you can easily create a new [variants](https://mui.com/customization/theme-components/#adding-new-component-variants) for your components (See the list of supported components in this [RFC](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/21749#:%7E:text=support%20this%20API.-,Progress,-Here%20is%20a)) using `createTheme()` which removes the need to create wrapper components. Below is the minimum example:

```js
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      variants: [
        {
          props: { variant: 'dashed' },
          style: {
            textTransform: 'none',
            border: `2px dashed grey${blue[500]}`,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
});
```

```js
export default function Demo() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Button variant="outlined">
        Outline
      </Button>
      <Button variant="dashed">
        Dashed
      </Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

For typescript users, you also need to update the variant definition using module augmentation.

```js
declare module '@mui/material/Button' {
  interface ButtonPropsVariantOverrides {
    dashed: true;
  }
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit GlobalThemeVariants Material Demo]

Comment: `createMuiTheme` is deprecated, we should use `createTheme`

Comment: On the MUI github there's a list of all components that support styling like this: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/21749#:~:text=support%20this%20API.-,Progress,-Here%20is%20a (under Progress)

Comment: Where do I add the last part tho? How to do module augmentation

Comment: @TusharShahi you can add it in any typescript files you want. I'd put it in the same place I define my custom theme like `theme.ts` because that's also where I create the new variant `dashed`.

Comment: I managed to do this. Added a new d.ts file. I think you should include `import ButtonPropsVariantOverrides` statement above your declare:

Comment: I think the modules were renamed. I had to do `declare module "@mui/material/Button"` to make typescript happy.

Comment: @emersonthis fixed. Yes, the path in the answer was from v4 beta or something. v5 components were moved to `@mui/material`/`@mui/lab`.

Comment: @NearHuscarl Wow that was fast!  Is there a way to specify hover state styles for the custom variant?

Comment: @emersonthis see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52596070/materialui-custom-hover-style), the code should be the same (`'&:hover' {...}`). I also updated my codesandbox for reference.

Comment: To get the styles to apply i have to add !important to each css property. anyone know why / a way around this?

Comment: Thanks for that RFC link. I was grinding my head trying to figure out why it wasn't working for TextField.

Comment: As of my writing this the `variant` prop appears to only be supported for a subset of MUI components (discussed in [this Github issue](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/33510))

Comment: @TusharShahi I needed to do this. Thanks.

Comment: TypeScript throws an error `Type string is not assignable to type '"dashed"...'` so I also needed to add `props: { variant: 'dashed' as ButtonProps['variant'] }`.

Comment: had to add `import '@mui/material/styles'` to the new `.d.ts`

Answer (score 0):

In case, you are trying to style a given mui component globaly with the version 5 , it should be something like:

```
 const theme = createTheme({
 components:{
    MuiTableCell:{
      styleOverrides:{
        root:{
          color: "red"
        }
      }
    }
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

to add on to NearHuscarl's answer if you want to customize a component that doesn't support custom variants yet, you can still change the style based on prop.  Same as in Yassine CHABLI's answer, but one level more.  I had to do this recently when I wanted to be able to past variant='largeText' to my MuiTooltips.

You're able to enter functions as the styleOveride and its passed an object with ownerState that has all the props you passed in at the top level.

From these docs: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/

Minimal version looks like this:

```js
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiTooltip: {
      styleOverrides: {
        tooltip: ({ ownerState }) => {
          if (ownerState?.variant === 'largeText') {
            return { fontSize: 16 };
          }
          return {};
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```