# Extending the default Material UI theme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to create my own theme using `createTheme()` but I want to start with the default material UI [theme](https://mui.com/customization/default-theme/) and just change a few properties in it.

If I call it like so:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: purple[500],
    },
    secondary: {
      main: green[500],
    },
  },
});
```

then I am still missing some properties that are needed for several components, *theme.palette.action.focus* for instance.
Is there a way to extend the default theme?

Comment: If you're talking about `TextField`, its focus color can be changed via the `color` prop

Comment: I don't want to change anything.. I want to use the default template and just override some properties.

Comment: You may want to have a look at variant although not all components are supported now. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66970148/9449426) answer for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the default theme by `styleOverrides` for `@mui/material` components.

Here is how to use it in the currently latest version.

```js
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
let theme = createTheme();
theme = createTheme(theme, {
  paleete: {
      ...theme.palette,
      action: {
          focus: "#e6e6e6",
          // other variants
      }
  },
  components: {
    MuiTableBody: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          // overrides here
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
export default theme;
```

Take a look at the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/g4yg1)

Comment: Thanks, but the `createTheme` command itself does not return the default theme as it is in the Material UI site (it's missing some properties as the 'theme.palette.action.focus'

Comment: "theme.palette.action.focus" doesn't exist in the current material-ui versrion. You have to define it yourself in "theme". Check the edits.

Comment: check the default theme in material-ui to which I linked in my question. It does contain 'theme.palette.action.focus'