# MUI v5 - Seperate styling from component file

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to separate styling from component File in MUI v5. The way I did it in v4 was using `makeStyles` like that:

`Page.style.js`:

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

export const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    background: "white",
  },
});
```

`Page.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import useStyles from "./Page.style";

const Page = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
        
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}></div>
  )
}
```

`makeStyles` is now legacy and I heard it will be deprecated next version.
What is the proper way to separate styling and component into different files in v5?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The recommended styling APIs in v5 are [`styled()`/`sx` prop](https://mui.com/system/basics). If you use `styled`, you can separate the styling code by creating a reusable styled component. The `sx` prop is more suitable for inline one-off style so it's not the best choice to use in this scenario:

```
const Div = styled('div')({
  background: "white",
});

export Div;
```

```
import React from "react";
import { Div } from "./Div";

const Page = () => {
  return (
    <Div />
  )
}
```

Besides that, you can also use [*variant*](https://mui.com/customization/theme-components/#heading-adding-new-component-variants) in MUI v5. The way it works is you create a custom styles and assign a name for it called variant so instead of specifying a className like before, you set the `variant` prop like this:

```
<Button variant="myCustomVariant">
  Button
</Button>
```

Custom variant can be created using `createTheme`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66970148/9449426) answer for more detail. Be aware that for now, this feature is not supported in all components:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      variants: [
        {
          props: { variant: 'myCustomVariant' },
          style: {
            textTransform: 'none',
            border: `2px dashed grey${blue[500]}`,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I find that styled() prop would fit well. I just dont know how to implement it with typescript without having errors.

Comment: @YahliGi you can add another question regarding that issue (please search on Stackoverflow first for duplication).

Comment: How to handle if I have multiple styles components to export ?

Comment: I'd join @YerlanYeszhanov question. Is it best to create a separate file with custom reusable styled components and import them where it's necessary?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend CSS Modules or Plain CSS because the other styling solution might get deprecated in the near future, one good example is the makeStyle which is now considered a Legacy styling solution.

You can find more information in Mui's webpage under the **Style library interoperability** section.

Answer (score 0):

It is suggested to use either `sx` or `styled`.

Document: https://mui.com/system/basics/